# VB.net Multithreaded keypresses

Tags: multithreading, keypress, keydown

I have a working 3D object viewer in VB.net (I know that VB.net is not the best language to use for this but still)

So if I press the W key the box moves up. If I press the D key it moves to the right. But I wanna do the simultaneously. And to do so I figured that I could give each key its own thread.

So the is the code I wound upwith.

```
Dim thread1 As System.Threading.Thread
Dim thread2 As System.Threading.Thread

Private Sub MoveUp_Keydown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles GlControl1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        If NumericUpDown1.Value < 100 Then
            NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value + 1
            Me.Refresh()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MoveUp1_Keydown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles GlControl1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        thread1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf MoveUp_Keydown)
    End If
End Sub
```

But the error I am getting is

```
error BC30518: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments
```

I have tried to google this but the problem is that nobody uses the threading for a keypress resulting in different solutions.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The compiler keeps you out of trouble early.  You cannot make this work, a window is not a thread-safe object in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without a Timer, but still using the GetKeyState() API:

```
Public Class Form1

    <Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Private Shared Function GetKeyState(ByVal nVirtKey As Integer) As Short
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If IsKeyDown(Keys.W) Then
            If NumericUpDown1.Value < 100 Then
                NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value + 1
                Me.Refresh()
            End If
        End If

        If IsKeyDown(Keys.D) Then
            If NumericUpDown2.Value < 100 Then
                NumericUpDown2.Value = NumericUpDown2.Value + 1
                Me.Refresh()
            End If
        End If

        ' ...etc...
    End Sub

    Private Function IsKeyDown(ByVal key As Keys) As Boolean
        Return GetKeyState(key) < 0
    End Function

End Class
```

The KeyDown() event will fire when any key is being held down, and you simply check each key you're interested in with GetKeyState().  There is no need for multiple threads...and I'm not even sure how that would work with form events.  I don't know what you wanted to do with the "D" key, so I just put in NumericUpDown2 so you could see each block can do a different thing.  You might not want to call `Me.Refresh` until the very bottom of the KeyDown() event so it only gets called once.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how that's gonna help me. It's like code to another program. I don't have any labels. What does each part do?

Comment: Also I don't wanna use a timer as in this case I think that it just looks bad. I need to use multithreading.

Comment: Removed the Timer and used GetKeyState() from within the KeyDown() event.

Comment: Will try this in a few mins and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Ok so that worked, ish. It registers the keys simultaneously but when I add or release a key it pauses for like half a second and then continues. Like A + W and it goes up and left, if I release A but keep W then it pauses for half a second and then it continues up.

Comment: Right...that's a function of the **operating system** and how it deals with "auto repeating" keystrokes.  The key is initially depressed and then has to be held down for a certain amount of time before it starts sending repeated keystrokes.  If you want more consistent behavior then move back to the Timer approach I originally suggested.

Comment: Ok, then I guess than I can live with it as I don't like timers at all. I have no idea why.